How to use a lemma that is defined in a Coq module?
How can I use the Lemma div_0_l from the standard library?
Somehow I cannot instantiate the module that is defined as
Module Type NDivProp (Import N : NAxiomsSig')(Import NP : NSubProp N).


Have you tried Require Import Arith. and then used that lemma by Nat.div_0_l?

Thank you, that solves my problem. I should have searched in Coq via Search or SearchPattern command instead

@HirokiChen: if you're so kind, please post your comment as an anwser, with a small working example demonstrating the solution. Thanks!

@AndrejBauer Sure :)

TL;DR
To use the lemma div_0_l, you should import the Arith library as follows.
Require Import Arith.
Search (0 / ?a = 0).
----
Nat.div_0_l: forall a : nat, a <> 0 -> 0 / a = 0

More about the Module Type
The reason why you cannot instantiate the module defined as
Module Type NDivProp (Import N : NAxiomsSig')(Import NP : NSubProp N).

is that the entire file is wrapped in a so-called Module Type. All the lemmas and other stuffs in this file can be used only if you pass two arguments to this module functor.
Putting it all together, NDivProp is a module type that depends on two other modules: one that adheres to NAxiomsSig' and another that conforms to NSubProp, which itself depends on the first module.
If you are interested you can look up the Coq's library:
(* Declared in Coq.Numbers.Natural.Abstract.NAxioms. *)
Module Type NAxiomsSig := NAxiomsMiniSig <+ OrderFunctions
  <+ NZParity.NZParity <+ NZPow.NZPow <+ NZSqrt.NZSqrt <+ NZLog.NZLog2
  <+ NZGcd.NZGcd <+ NZDiv.NZDiv <+ NZBits.NZBits <+ NZSquare.

and then PeanoNat says that Nat module implements these modules:
Module Nat
  <: NAxiomsSig
  <: UsualDecidableTypeFull
  <: OrderedTypeFull
  <: TotalOrder.

The module type design, to some extent, resembles the notion of class in OOP languages, you can defined interfaces and some concrete object that implements these interfaces but you cannot directly use interfaces since they do not have an instance.
